# Prove that $Tr(A^m) =\sum_{} \lambda^m_i$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

> **My problem**: The coefficients of the characteristic polynomial are
>   expressed as $\chi_A(\lambda) = \lambda^n + D_1\lambda^{n-1}+...+D_n$.
>   Prove that $Tr(A^m) =\sum_{} \lambda^m_i$, where $\lambda_i$ are the
>   eigenvalues of $A$ (a matrix) and from this prove the reccurent
>   formula:
>
> $mD_m + D_{m-1}Tr(A) + D_{m-2}Tr(A^2)+...+Tr(A^m)$ = 0

**My solution**: Every diagonalisable matrix $A$ can be expressed as the product od the similar diagonal matrix $D$ with the eigenvalues on its diagonal and the bases containing the eigenvectors.  Traces of those matrixes are same: $Tr(A) = Tr(D) = \sum_{i=1}^na_{ii} = \sum_{i=i}^n  \lambda_i$, so the same follows for $Tr(A^m) = Tr(D^m) = \sum_{i=i}^n  \lambda^m_i$, for $1\le m \le n$.

I think I would prove that reccurent formula with Viet's relation, not sure how. Is there any proof of $Tr(A) = Tr(D)$?

Comment: I think in the recurrence formula the index should be $n$ not $m$.

Comment: I forgot to write for $1\le m \le n$

Comment: More generally, a matrix is always unitarily upper triangularizable (Schur theorem), so $A^{m}\sim T^{m},$ and the diagonal entries of $T^{m}$ are the $m$th powers of the eigenvalues of $A.$ Then trace is preserved under similarity, which proves the first part.

Comment: Can't resist citing myself: The second part of your problem is Theorem 2.6 in [*The trace Cayley-Hamilton theorem*](http://www.cip.ifi.lmu.de/~grinberg/algebra/trach.pdf). Of course, the proof I give is more general than necessary here (the whole point of that note is making do without eigenvalues).

Comment: Ah, here's a reference for your exact situation: Theorem 1 in [arXiv:hep-th/0701116v1](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0701116v1). Needless to say, the authors of this paper are hardly the first to invent it, but they seem to have written the proof quite nicely.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove the recurrence formula, you would rather applies the Hamilton theorem which says that every matrix satisfies its own characteristic equation.
As such, in the characteristic equation, substitute $\lambda$ by $A$. and then apply the equality on the trace operator given that: the trace of the sum of matrices is equal to sum of traces of each matrix.

Best

Comment: I don't think the question follows from Cayley-Hamuilton. It does when $m \geq n$, but that's not the interesting case.